# Ways to break text after a certain number of words or characters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, text, newline, line-breaks

Given a **string**:

"`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut`", break it after

1. **4 words**
2. **40 characters**

using a maximum language version of `C# 4` (in order to be compatible with the Mono platform).

---

Update/Edit:

**Regex Implementations**:

ad #2 - split after 40 characters (see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2759399))

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex.Split(
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut"
, "(.{40})"
, RegexOptions.Multiline)
.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
.ToArray();
```

---

This post serves as a **community wiki**.

Comment: Seeing that you are using lorem ipsum, i.e. a language that is not English, implies that you want to break text for various languages. That is a very demanding task and there is no easy way to do it because you often cannot rely on whitespace and have to take care of whether symbols go before or after the wrap. At least, you should state what you have tried and explain what languages must be supported.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that is not a language that is type set test string http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum

Comment: The unicode standard defines a method in C that you could convert to C#.

Comment: @Blam: Yes, I know. It's not English (and not really Latin either, BTW), and hence we can surmise that the OP means "any language" rather than a specific language.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you could consider it Latin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum#English_translation

Comment: @Blam "The lorem ipsum text is typically a section of a Latin text by Cicero with words altered, added and removed that make it nonsensical in meaning and not proper Latin." -Wikipedia (dur)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: No, you can only assume that OP wants to split _any_ text, it might be a specific language.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Not quite; it breaks some of the original Latin words apart and hence cannot be considered Latin, just Latin-lookalike.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Interesting response. I realize, one approach is through PREG Regex... https://gist.github.com/2759399. Another through LINQ. I had this question in my mind for a while after googling it now and then. Really, a compendium of stack-expertise would be nice. Any contribution is thus welcome.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: In that case, giving a sample text in that language would make more sense than in a different language than the one the OP wants to split. Lorem ipsum is fine for showing what a paragraph as a whole looks like without looking at single words or characters, but in my opinion it doesn't make so much sense as a test input string for operations on the character level if you're targetting a particular language.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper if he's splitting by whitespace, which makes sense, then the answer below should do it.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Lore-ipsum is usually used when someone wants to emphasize that the text or the language doesn't matter.     No more, no less.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: That's why I asked which target languages need to be supported above; the splitting by whitespace approach only works for languages that do use whitespace between words. And even then, other wrapping indicators in long words such as hyphens might have to be looked at.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: My point is that the language *does* matter when talking about line breaking.

Comment: I like the open-mindedness `O.R.Mapper` introduced. Let's go with that theme.... As `Tim Schmelter` said: it "might be any text"

Comment: I am just curious about how some people found a reason to upvote the question. it doesn't even include a question(the only `?` mark is in the title)

Comment: @L.B For you, any question that doesn't repeat itself in the question-body, is subject to be downvoted and closed? And despite checking for similar questions, you can't agree on the question being warranted? Let me know how I can clarify or improve it...

Comment: @Blam: I haven't (yet?) voted on this question or any answer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 4 words

As O. R. Mapper said in his comment, this really depends on your ability to define a "word" in a given string and what the delimiters are between words. However, assuming you can define the delimiter as whitespace, then this should work:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string delimiterPattern = @"\s+"; // I'm using whitespace as a delimiter here

// find all spaces between words
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, delimiterPattern);

// if we found at least 4 delimiters, cut off the string at the 4th (index = 3)
// delimiter. Else, just keep the original string
string firstFourWords = (matches.Count >= 4)
    ? (text.Substring(0, matches[3].Index))
    : (text);
```

---

> 40 characters

```
string firstFortyCharacters = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(text.Length, 40));
```

---

> Both

Combining both, we can get the shorter one:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string delimiterPattern = @"\s+"; // I'm using whitespace as a delimiter here

// find all spaces between words
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, delimiterPattern);

// if we found at least 4 delimiters, cut off the string at the 4th (index = 3)
// delimiter. Else, just keep the original string
string firstFourWords = (matches.Count >= 4)
    ? (text.Substring(0, matches[3].Index))
    : (text);

string firstFortyCharacters = text.Substring(0, Math.Min(text.Length, 40));

string result = (firstFourWords.Length > 40) ? (firstFortyCharacters) : (firstFourWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question #2: Place this in a static class and you get a nice extension method that inserts a string at given intervals in another string

```
public static string InsertAtIntervals(this string s, int interval, string value)
{
    if (s == null || s.Length <= interval) {
        return s;
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = interval * ((s.Length - 1) / interval); i > 0; i -= interval) {
        sb.Insert(i, value);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```