# Adding Character between numbers

Tags: php, string

I have an integer `$client_version=1000` I do need to add dots between every number in this integer so it looks like `1.0.0.0` and save it in new variable as string.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's very common for dotted version numbers to use double-digits, like `1.3.10.4`, never mind when you get into patch levels and have versions like `3.2.10-p370`. You probably don't want to store a version as an integer.

Comment: @Khamees Smith Don't feel obliged to immediately rush to select an answer, giving editors more time in taking care of formatting and overall quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PHP offers the function [array str_split ( string $string [, int $split_length = 1 ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to convert a string to a character-array or blocks of characters.
  In your case, invoking `str_split((string)1000, 1)` or `str_split((string)1000)` will result in:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 0
      [2] => 0
      [3] => 0
  )
  ```

  ***Code:***

  ```
  implode('.',str_split((string)1000))
  ```

  **Result:** `1.0.0.0`

---

- For a more general, yet less well known approach, based on Regular Expression see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lsauer/2759399) and this tangentially related [topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548100/ways-to-break-text-after-a-certain-number-of-words-or-characters-in-c).

  ***Code:***

  ```
  preg_match_all('/(.{1})/', (string)1000, $matches);
  echo implode('.', $matches[0]);
  ```

  **Result:** `1.0.0.0`

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough:

```
$client_version = 1000; 
$dotted = join(".",str_split($client_version));
```

Note that this will always split it so that there is only one character between the dots. If you want something like `1.00.0`, you'll need to change your question to explain more about what you're trying to do and what patterns you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_split](http://php.net/str_split) to get an array of chars and then [implode](http://php.net/implode) them.

```
$client_version = 1000;
$client_version_chars = str_split($client_version);
$client_version_with_dots = implode('.', $client_version_chars);
```